# CDN for a RESTful API?

Tags: rest, cdn

I have a RESTful API with resources updates once a week. That is, for each resource, I update it once and week and allow clients to access it. It's an ever changing calculator.

There are probably 10,000 resources which *could* be requested.

Is it possible to put something like this behind a CDN? Traditionally CDNs are for undeniably static content, ie images. I'm not sure where my situation sits in the spectrum of dynamic <-> static.

Cheers

Comment: What type of resource are we talking about? How big?  Your situation is pretty static if it only changes once per week.

Comment: controlling the cache policy well, and you'll be fine @Max

Comment: GET requests returning XML and JSON files

Comment: Cache control won't help much. 90% of the resources might not even get called, and if they are, will get called a few times only. It wont be a mass of repetitive calls

Comment: How big are they?  The normal XML/JSON responses aren't too big and probably don't warrant a CDN.  But you can cache them in memory locally and cache them remotely on the client with cache-control headers.  If your files are small and you are looking to reduce time for your clients, look into a global DNS.  For small files, clients are probably spending as much time on the DNS lookup as they are on the download.

Comment: Yes the files are tiny. Bytes of information.

Answer (score 5):

> 90% of the resources might not even get called, and if they are, will
>   get called a few times only. It wont be a mass of repetitive calls.

Right there in your comments, you just showed me that a CDN is not beneficial to you.

Usually how a CDN works is the first call it is downloaded from the main server to the regional CDN node then delivered to the client meaning the first GET will have no improvements.  The following GETs to the same regional node will have the speed improvement.  If you have little to no repetitive calls, then you will not see any noticeable improvement.

As I said in the comments, for small files, clients are probably spending as much time on the DNS lookup as they are on the download.  Look into a global DNS solution (like Anycast) to reduce connection times.  This is easy to setup and requires little to no maintenance.

Comment: Thanks. I will definitely look into it. Our biggest issue is the physical distance between the host (UK) and client (AUS). 500ms of latency on average. However isn't it possible to download and cache all of the requests at select CDN nodes?

Comment: That isn't how a CDN normally works.  The new data has to be retrieved by the local node first.  So it would only help for subsequent requests.  Regional CDN nodes only cache data for a short period of time to save space, otherwise, they would need to store tons of data in every location.  You may be able to preload, I guess it depends on the CDN, but it isn't normally how it works.  Maybe you should just consider getting a secondary server in Asia, Australia, or the Western US.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's entirely reasonable to put it behind a CDN if you think your content will reach the appropriate level of scale. As long as the cache-control headers are set such that the latest content is loaded when the cached version may be stale, you'll be fine.

The main benefit of CDNs comes when resources are requested from a variety of different sources, and so `siteY.com` can use the same cached version of a resource as `siteX.com`. Do you anticipate your resources will be requested from various different sources?

Comment: I mostly need it for the geographic proximity to clients without having to deploy to multiple data centres. The load itself wont be huge but low latency is critical